# HTML upload file small manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

When I use this code **on IE8**, the file is sent through the HTTP request fine:

```
<form action="http:localhost:8080/myApp"
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p>
Type some text (if you like):<br>
<input type="text" name="textline" size="30">
</p>
<p>
Please specify a file<br>
<input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
</p>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>
```

but when I add another intermediate button, 'Add file', as you can see below instead of pressing the 'browse' button itself, the file isn't sent to the server side, why??

```
<form action="http:localhost:8080/myApp"
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<p>
Type some text (if you like):<br>
<input type="text" name="textline" size="30">
</p>
<p>
Please specify a file<br>
<input id="fileChooser" type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
</p>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('fileChooser').click()">Add File</button>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the real input of type file hidden by setting its opacity to 0 then put the fake button on top of it, with smaller `z-index` value. This way when clicking the fake button, user will actually click the real button underneath and you will achieve the visual effect you desire.

Answer (score 2):

Change the event handler:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('fileChooser').click(); return false">Add File</button>
```

Your button was acting as a "select" element. You could also make it work by explicitly setting the button type, I think:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('fileChooser').click()" type='button'>Add File</button>
```

Now, this works in Chrome, maybe Safari, and you say now that it works in IE8 as far as getting the file chooser up.  It won't work in Firefox, however, because Firefox appears to be more strict about what you can do to file inputs.

Comment: I tried and it didn't help. I also didn't understand the point of this correction. My problem is not to open the OS file-chooser. It is being opened anyway. The problem is that afterwords, on pressing on submit the file isn't sent eventually in my second implementation.

Comment: @Spiderman if it works in IE8 it's probably because IE8 defaults button type to "button" and not "submit".  However if the file chooser is choosing the file, and the file input is actually updated (you see the file name, right?), then it makes no sense that the file isn't being posted.  I'll set up a test for that.

Answer (score 0):

OK read some articles. Apparently that's just impossible.
I hope that HTML5 and IE9 will improve the customization of the annoying upload button, in many aspects.